# Why is model-viewer not working on safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, 3d, model-viewer

I am trying to put some 3D Models on my website but it seems that it works only on Android and Windows so far, don't know why. I tried to use different formats for files but still nothing. Even if I go to the website where is the documentation, ***[here](https://modelviewer.dev/examples/augmentedreality/)***, nothing shows up so I thought maybe safari doesn't support 3D Models anymore?

Here is a little piece of my code as I might have written something wrong.

```
<div class="container-fluid ml-auto mr-auto" style="margin-bottom: 60px; margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col">
        <model-viewer disable-zoom poster="3d_assets/untitled.png"src=" 3d_assets/place_holder.gltf" ios-src="3d_assets/place_holder.usdz" alt="A 3d thing" auto-rotate camera-controls></model-viewer>
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-center">
      <p class="model-text">
        text text
        text text
      </p>
      <p class="model-sm-text">
         smaller
         smaller
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
model-viewer{
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.model-text{
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.model-sm-text{
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console? Or is this iOS Safari?

Comment: There are no errors in the developer console. The 3d model just doesn't appear on Safari on IOS. Even though the model is loaded, the browser won't display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the **src** part you put this:

```
src=" 3d_assets/place_holder.gltf"
```

what happened is that you put a space before '3d' so that means the file will have a space in the beginning and will not be found.
so the correct code would be this:

```
src="3d_assets/place_holder.gltf"
```

(without the space)

Answer (score 0):

I found this is helpful

```
customElements.get("model-viewer").minimumRenderScale = 1;
```

You can learn more here https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/1521